# How to remove the special characters in the columns and convert the columns into float data

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the last characters in the column and convert the column into float. The column type is object.

my column like this :

```
train['latitude'].head()
             -95.369803)
1             -95.369803)
2    -117.07184056399967)
3     -77.86070029399963)
4            -122.419416)
Name: latitude, dtype: object
```

I tried this code, but getting errors,

```
 train['latitude'] = train['latitude'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r')', ' ', x)).replace('', np.float64(0)).astype('float64')
```

please help me how to convert object  to float

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-99-b5cdc7554b0a> in <module>()
    ----> 1 df = train['latitude'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r')', ' ', x)).replace('', np.float64(0)).astype('float64')

    6 frames
    pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

    /usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
        867     if source.next is not None:
        868         assert source.next == ")"
    --> 869         raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
        870 
        871     if flags & SRE_FLAG_DEBUG:

    error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 0
```

Comment: None of the 5 answer good enough to accept?

Answer (score 3):

I assume the column name is `latitude`

You can actually remove the last character from the column value and then convert it to float.

`df["latitude"].astype(str).str[:-1].astype(np.float64)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.rstrip`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': ["-95.369803)", "-95.369803)", "-117.07184056399967)"]})
df["latitude"] = df["latitude"].str.rstrip(")").astype(float)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     latitude
0  -95.369803
1  -95.369803
2 -117.071841
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
train['latitude'] = train['latitude'].astype(str).str[:1].astype(np.float64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
train['latitude'] = train['latitude'].str.replace(')', '').astype(np.float64)
```

You will now have all the values as float after removing the last character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

`train['latitude'].str.extract(r'(-\d+.\d+)').astype(float)`